# Grunt - Queueing a task to run after a previous task completes

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, minify, task-queue

I looked at the official Grunt documentation for creating tasks here

http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks

I have two tasks that I want to do, but the second one cannot run until after the first one completes. That's because the second task takes the output from the first task and uses it to create new output.

To break it down

My project involves Bootstrap, so it has a lot of unused code. My first objective is to remove the unused code with `uncss`. I would then take the output from this new css file and minify it with `cssmin`.

Here was the exact example from gruntjs

```
grunt.registerTask('foo', 'My "foo" task.', function() {
  // Enqueue "bar" and "baz" tasks, to run after "foo" finishes, in-order.
  grunt.task.run('bar', 'baz');
  // Or:
  grunt.task.run(['bar', 'baz']);
});
```

I tried to apply this to my code here

```
grunt.registerTask('default', 'uncss', function() {
    grunt.task.run('cssmin');
});
```

This means that when `grunt` is entered, the default is to run the `uncss` task first, wait for it to complete, then run the `cssmin` task. However I got this output

> Running "default" task
>
> Running "cssmin:css" (cssmin) task
>
> 1 file created. 3.38kb -> 2.27kb
>
> Done, without errors

Here is my `initConfig`

```
uncss: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            'directory/assets/stylesheets/tidy.css': ['directory/*.html', 'directory/views/*.html']
            }
        }
    },
    
    cssmin: {
        css: {
            files: {
                'directory/assets/stylesheets/styles.min.css': ['directory/assets/stylesheets/styles.css']
            }
        }
    }
```

In other words, I have two stylesheets in my folder. One contains the custom styles I created, and another contains Bootstrap minified. By running `uncss`, I will get a new css file named `tidy.css`.

The cssmin task is supposed to look for this tidy.css file and minify it resulting in a new `styles.min.css` file.

I can get this to work, but I have to manually run one task and then run another one. How can I automate this to have them run in sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, best practice is to use npm package to load all tasks automatically:

```
// Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
```

here are two grunt tasks:

```
one: {
      wake up...
    },

two: {
      dress up...
    },
```

and here is how you run one after the other

```
grunt.registerTask('oneThenOther', [
    'one',
    'two'
  ]);
```

Comment: You had the most detailed response. Your answer gets accepted

Answer (score 1):

You're close. When registering your [alias task](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#alias-tasks) pass an array of tasks in the sequence you desire instead of a single task.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss', 'cssmin']);
```

Alternatively, the sequence can be specified via the CLI:

```
> grunt uncss cssmin
```

Comment: That was helpful too. You get an upvote. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out part of the problem was I was specifying the wrong file under cssmin.

Changing my cssmin config to

```
cssmin: {
    css: {
        files: {
            'directory/assets/stylesheets/styles.min.css': ['directory/assets/stylesheets/tidy.css']
            }
        }
    }
```

and then registering the tasks in an array solved it

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['uncss', 'cssmin']);
```

Note that the tasks must be specified in that order.